# Call to undefined function _civicrm_api3_basic_get when using CiviRepeat module

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civimember, api

I am using civicrm 4.7.17

When I go to the page sitename/admin/config/civicrm/civirepeat, I get the error

Call to undefined function _civicrm_api3_basic_get in Event.php on line 133

I figured out that the Event.php file is located in the civicrm/api/v3 folder and the function _civicrm_api3_basic_get is defined in the file utils.php in the same folder.

Why do I get the error even though the function has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Civirepeat seems like a pretty old module that's no longer supported.

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=3329.msg76694#msg76694

Maybe if you explain your reasons for using the module it can be done using existing features as the above forum link suggests.

Comment: More than that - repeating events are a built-in feature of CiviCRM 4.6+, so ignore anything the forum suggests!  Just check out the [repeating events documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/repeating-events/)